# Xcode 7.2 Unable to 'reset' my iOS Distribution signing identity

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to upload an application on "App Store" using my clients credentials, but when I click on "Upload to App Store", It shows error:

[image]

And when I click on Reset, it gives error:

[image]

I have checked in preferences that I have the iOS distribution licence and I am using Team Agent's credentials.

Comment: It depends on the permission which your agent has provided you

Comment: did you check certificates in your keychain

Comment: @Abhi: What certificates do I need to check for?

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder What are the permissions that could be missing?

Comment: download new distribution certificate, add to KeyChain, Remove old one certificate, also make new provisional profile using distribution cer, and added in Xcode Accout.

Comment: @KiritModi : I tried doing that by dragging and dropping the certificate but it does not show in the KeyChain.

Comment: Download and Double click on it, also remove old one which is expired.

Comment: There is no expired certificate.

Comment: @Ravi you can check your permissions , login to developer.apple.com then goto membership tab there your role is written . Please check this.

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder : My role is "Agent"


And Entity Type: In-House / Enterprise

Is that the reason?

Comment: Also option to "Export" my existing iOS distribution signing identity is "greyed" out.

Comment: You need to have the access of developer

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder:  How to get developer access and which developer access are you talking about?

Comment: The person who is admin can provide you the developer access from his developer account

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder: I am "Team Agent". There is no one else in the team.

Comment: Please goto https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/ng/users_roles and check

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder: Thank you, so much for all your help. But every time I click on the link provided by you. I am signed out of itunes.

Comment: you need to sign in then only the link will open

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder: I logged in, and opened the link and it says that you are logged out.

Message: "You've been signed out. Sign in to iTunes Connect."

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110372/discussion-between-reshmi-majumder-and-ravi-rawal).